# Почему PyCharm при нажатии `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `L` ставит пробел перед знаком ':'

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: При нажатии Ctrl + Alt + L PyCharm автоматически ставит пробел перед двоеточием. Настройки я не менял, они стандартные, как исправить без понятия]

При нажатии <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> PyCharm автоматически ставит пробел перед двоеточием. Настройки я не менял, они стандартные, как исправить без понятия

Comment: Если я правильно помню, что делает эта комбинация, то это форматирование кода. Собственно это на картинке и происходит. Поэтому ищите в настройках стили форматирования и настраивайте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]**Для решения данной проблемы необходимо выполнить следующие действия:**

1. Нажимаем <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Переходим в Editor
3. Далее Code Style
4. Далее Python
5. Далее в Spaces
6. Далее Other
7. Убираем галочку у пункта Before ':'

**Теперь PyCharm не ставит пробел перед двоеточием**

Answer (score 0):

Измени настройки горячих клавиш
У тебя английский интерфейс `PyCharm`, так что найдешь их по такому пути:
`File` - `Settings` (или нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, по умолчанию) - `Keymap` - `Main Menu` - `Code` - `Reformat Code`
Щелкаешь правой кнопкой по этой строке - и самый нижний пункт - `Remove Ctrl-Alt-L`

Comment: я думаю, что автор вопроса не просто так нажимает Ctrl_Alt_L. Видимо он что то хочет достигнуть. А удаление этой комбинации - немного странный способ решить проблему.

Comment: Я просто хочу что бы при исполнении данной комбинации пай чарм исправлял код по стандарту PEP8, как он делал ранее, но вместо того он захотел перед двоеточием ставить пробел